# Express: empty req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I have simply express server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs'
});

const _PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', 'views');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(require('./routers/login'));

serverStart();

async function serverStart(){
    try{
        app.listen(_PORT);
        console.log('[SERVER] Server is listening port ' + _PORT + ' now.');
    }catch(error){ 
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

And simply router:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');

const router = Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'main page'
    });
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Why 'req.body' is always empty?
I tried to send POST query from "Postman", but it isn't work.
It's working only with x-www-form-urlencoded query, but I want to send json query.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

UPD: postman screenshot
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkgDh.png)

Comment: try with app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: Have you tried without the `*+` in the type? `bodyparser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' })`. The examples given in the [readme](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#type) are more like `application/json` or `*/json`.

Comment: Please show us the postman command line you're using.  Are you sending a body? If so, how is it encoded?  This all works if your middleware covers the actual format of the body you are sending so one of those two isn't aligning.

Comment: @David784 yes, but it isn't working

Comment: @jfriend00 done

Comment: Add `console.log(req.headers["content-type"]` to your request handler and see what you're getting.  If you're getting `application/json`, then fix your middleware to match that content type.

Comment: If you want to send JSON, replace this line `app.use(bodyparser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));` with this one `app.use(bodyparser.json());`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been try your code and it's working fine, you only have to change your code:

```js
app.use(bodyparser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
```

With this code below:

```js
app.use(bodyparser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
```

> **Note:** If you're use the latest version of `express`, then you should not to install `body-parser`, Because `body-parser` is already included.

So, you can use this code below:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I hope it can help you.